# ant build failed xxx\xxx\build.xml:49: Java returned: -1

Tags: ant, blackberry, blackberry-jde, build.xml

I am trting to build Blackberry project and generate the cod file.
My environment is Windows 7 and the apache-ant version is 1.8.2.
I have encountered two problems and they all lead to failure.

The command I used to build is "ant -Dbuild_env=prod"
Below is part of the code in the build.xml file.

```
<property file="build.properties" />
<property environment="SystemVariable"/>
<!--<property name="jde.home" value="${SystemVariable.JDE_HOME}"/> -->
<property name="jde.home" value="E:\eclipse-blackberry\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack5.0.0_5.0.0.25\components"/>
<property name="bb_sign_pwd" value="${SystemVariable.BB_SIGN_PWD}"/>
<property name="jde.sigtooljar" value="${jde.home}/bin/SignatureTool.jar"/>
```

First problem:
If I use the code

```
<property name="jde.home" value="${SystemVariable.JDE_HOME}"/>
```

to run the building, 
the error(error 1) is

**"jde home must be a directory"**,

but if I use the code

```
<property name="jde.home" value="E:\eclipse-blackberry\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack5.0.0_5.0.0.25\components"/>
```

it works but still build failed.
I think may be the ant cannot find the enviromental varialbe although I set the enviromental varialbe "JDE_HOME" in the Windows to "E:\eclipse-blackberry\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack5.0.0_5.0.0.25\components".

Second problem:
Use the code

```
<property name="jde.home" value="E:\eclipse-blackberry\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack5.0.0_5.0.0.25\components"/>
```

instead but another error(error 2) is

**"XXX\XXX\XXX\build.xml:49:Java returned: -1"**

Line 48 to 50 in the build.xml is like this

```
48:<target name="build" description="Builds Project" depends="init"/>
49:<rapc jdehome="${jde.home}" jdkhome="${SystemVariable.JAVA_HOME}" destdir="${output.dir}" output="${app.name}_${build_env}" quiet="false" generatesourcelist="true"/>
50:<jdp title="${app.title}" type="cldc" vendor="XXX Inc." version="${app.version}" description="XXX Application" icon="${icon.path}" focusicon="true" startuptier="7" ribbonposition="0"/>
```

Is there any one can help and tell me why there is error 1 and error 2?
Thanks.

Comment: Try to familiarize yourself with Stackoverflow Markdown markup for asking (and answering questions). This is horrible to read.

Comment: Thanks for advising, this is the first time I asked a question on Stackoverflow.

Comment: The new updated JDK caused problems for me too. I could fix it by specifying both jdehome and jdkhome explicitly (without assuming they will be populated from system variables). Try setting  `jdkhome="${jdk.home}"` in the rapc after explicitly specifying the jdk.home path.